# Array for multidimensional array with depth

Tags: php, recursion

I have a big problem (apparently so simple to solve) that I have been trying for more than 24 hours to create a function to turn the array into multidimensional with **depth**.

My array is

```
$array = array(
    array("name" => "Root_1", "depth"=> "1"),
    array("name" => "Children","depth"=> "2"),
    array("name" => "Children", "depth"=> "2"),
    array("name" => "Children", "depth"=> "2"),
    array("name" => "Children","depth"=> "3"),
    array("name" => "Children","depth"=> "3"),
    array("name" => "Children","depth"=> "3"),
    array("name" => "Root_2", "depth"=> "1"),
    array("name" => "Children", "depth"=> "2"),
    array("name" => "Children", "depth"=> "2"),
    array("name" => "Children", "depth"=> "2")
)
```

And I want the output to be:

```
$array = array(
  array("name" => "Root_1", "depth"=> "1", "children" => array(
        array("name" => "Children", "depth"=> "2", "children" => array()),
        array("name" => "Children", "depth"=> "2", "children" => array()),
        array("name" => "Children", "depth"=> "2", "children" => array(
                array("name" => "Children", "depth"=> "3", "children" => array()),
                array("name" => "Children", "depth"=> "3", "children" => array()),
                array("name" => "Children", "depth"=> "3", "children" => array())
            )
        )), 
  array("name" => "Root_2", "depth"=> "1", "children" => array(
        array("name" => "Children", "depth"=> "2", "children" => array()),
        array("name" => "Children", "depth"=> "2", "children" => array()),
        array("name" => "Children", "depth"=> "2", "children" => array(
                array("name" => "Children", "depth"=> "3", "children" => array()),
                array("name" => "Children", "depth"=> "3", "children" => array()),
                array("name" => "Children", "depth"=> "3", "children" => array())
            )
        )), 
);
```

What I've tried:

```
<?php


function createArray($array, $depth) {
$result = array();
$item = array();


if(isset($array["depth"])) {
    if(intval($array["depth"]) >= $depth) {
        array_push($result, $array);
    }
} else {
    foreach($array as $value) {
        $depthToInt = intval($value["depth"]);
        if($depthToInt === $depth) {
            array_push($result, $value);
            $item = $value;
        } else {
            $item["children"] = createArray($value, $item["depth"]);
        }
    }
}
return $result;
```

}

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried in the past 24h?

Comment: @ChinLeung I'm still trying to tweak the code: https://ideone.com/YhgxdI

Comment: From your desired output I'm assuming that all `depth => 2` are children of `Root_1` **and** `Root_2`. But how do you differentiate which "Children of depth 2" are assigned the "Children of depth 3" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so clearly we want a recursive solution.

For each item (starting with virtual root) we want to retrieve children. Let's say we get children by filtering out everything that is *not* children.

What are our criteria for the filter?

1. Child has a depth larger than the parent.
2. Child has an index larger than the parent.
3. Child belongs in a block of items with same depth. Let's shuffle this as child has index smaller than start of next block. Let's call this index smaller than a limit.

So we need:

1. Function that gets children for given index, depth, and limit.
2. Helper function that gets limit for given index.

Here is what I ended up with. I don't think this is perfect (I vaguely doubt my limit logic there), but it's mostly there for your example data.

```php
$array = array(
    array( 'name' => 'Root_1', 'depth' => '1' ),
    array( 'name' => 'Children 1-1', 'depth' => '2' ),
    array( 'name' => 'Children 1-2', 'depth' => '2' ),
    array( 'name' => 'Children 1-2-1', 'depth' => '3' ),
    array( 'name' => 'Children 1-3', 'depth' => '2' ),
    array( 'name' => 'Children 1-3-1', 'depth' => '3' ),
    array( 'name' => 'Children 1-3-2', 'depth' => '3' ),
    array( 'name' => 'Children 1-3-3', 'depth' => '3' ),
    array( 'name' => 'Root_2', 'depth' => '1' ),
    array( 'name' => 'Children 2-1', 'depth' => '2' ),
    array( 'name' => 'Children 2-2', 'depth' => '2' ),
    array( 'name' => 'Children 2-3', 'depth' => '2' ),
    array( 'name' => 'Children 2-3-1', 'depth' => '3' ),
    array( 'name' => 'Children 2-3-2', 'depth' => '3' ),
    array( 'name' => 'Children 2-3-3', 'depth' => '3' ),
);

function getChildren( $array, $index = - 1 ) {

    $depth = isset( $array[ $index ]['depth'] ) ? (int) $array[ $index ]['depth'] : 0;
    $limit = $index === - 1 ? count( $array ) - 1 : findLimit( $array, $index );

    $result = array_filter( $array, function ( $item, $key ) use ( $index, $depth, $limit ) {

        $isDeeper      = (int) $item['depth'] === $depth + 1;
        $isAfter       = $key > $index;
        $isBeforeLimit = $key <= $limit;

        return $isDeeper && $isAfter && $isBeforeLimit;
    }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH );

    foreach ( $result as $key => $item ) {
        $result[ $key ]['children'] = getChildren( $array, $key );
    }

    return $result;
}

function findLimit( $array, $index ) {
    $depth   = (int) $array[ $index ]['depth'];
    $limit   = $index;
    $current = $limit + 1;

    while ( isset( $array[ $current ] ) && ( (int) $array[ $current ]['depth'] > $depth ) ) {
        $current ++;
        $limit ++;
    }

    return $limit;
}

$result = getChildren( $array );

var_dump( $result );
```

Result:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(6) "Root_1"
    ["depth"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["children"]=>
    array(3) {
      [1]=>
      array(3) {
        ["name"]=>
        string(12) "Children 1-1"
        ["depth"]=>
        string(1) "2"
        ["children"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
      }
      [2]=>
      array(3) {
        ["name"]=>
        string(12) "Children 1-2"
        ["depth"]=>
        string(1) "2"
        ["children"]=>
        array(1) {
          [3]=>
          array(3) {
            ["name"]=>
            string(14) "Children 1-2-1"
            ["depth"]=>
            string(1) "3"
            ["children"]=>
            array(0) {
            }
          }
        }
      }
      [4]=>
      array(3) {
        ["name"]=>
        string(12) "Children 1-3"
        ["depth"]=>
        string(1) "2"
        ["children"]=>
        array(3) {
          [5]=>
          array(3) {
            ["name"]=>
            string(14) "Children 1-3-1"
            ["depth"]=>
            string(1) "3"
            ["children"]=>
            array(0) {
            }
          }
          [6]=>
          array(3) {
            ["name"]=>
            string(14) "Children 1-3-2"
            ["depth"]=>
            string(1) "3"
            ["children"]=>
            array(0) {
            }
          }
          [7]=>
          array(3) {
            ["name"]=>
            string(14) "Children 1-3-3"
            ["depth"]=>
            string(1) "3"
            ["children"]=>
            array(0) {
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  [8]=>
  array(3) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(6) "Root_2"
    ["depth"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["children"]=>
    array(3) {
      [9]=>
      array(3) {
        ["name"]=>
        string(12) "Children 2-1"
        ["depth"]=>
        string(1) "2"
        ["children"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
      }
      [10]=>
      array(3) {
        ["name"]=>
        string(12) "Children 2-2"
        ["depth"]=>
        string(1) "2"
        ["children"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
      }
      [11]=>
      array(3) {
        ["name"]=>
        string(12) "Children 2-3"
        ["depth"]=>
        string(1) "2"
        ["children"]=>
        array(3) {
          [12]=>
          array(3) {
            ["name"]=>
            string(14) "Children 2-3-1"
            ["depth"]=>
            string(1) "3"
            ["children"]=>
            array(0) {
            }
          }
          [13]=>
          array(3) {
            ["name"]=>
            string(14) "Children 2-3-2"
            ["depth"]=>
            string(1) "3"
            ["children"]=>
            array(0) {
            }
          }
          [14]=>
          array(3) {
            ["name"]=>
            string(14) "Children 2-3-3"
            ["depth"]=>
            string(1) "3"
            ["children"]=>
            array(0) {
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm a bit late, but if you're interested in an non-recursive solution, here's a simple *one-pass-only* loop (*O(n)*):

```
<?php

function treeify(array $input): array
{
    $result = [];
    $path = [];

    foreach ($input as &$entry) {
        $entry['children'] = [];

        $depth = $entry['depth'] - 1;
        $path = \array_slice($path, 0, $depth);
        $path[] = &$entry;

        0 === $depth
            ? $result[] = &$entry
            : $path[$depth - 1]['children'][] = &$entry;
    }

    return $result;
}

print_r(treeify([
    ['name' => 'Root_1', 'depth' => 1],
        ['name' => 'Children', 'depth' => 2],
        ['name' => 'Children', 'depth' => 2],
        ['name' => 'Children', 'depth' => 2],
            ['name' => 'Children', 'depth' => 3],
            ['name' => 'Children', 'depth' => 3],
            ['name' => 'Children', 'depth' => 3],
                ['name' => 'Children', 'depth' => 4],
        ['name' => 'Children', 'depth' => 2],
    ['name' => 'Root_2', 'depth'=> 1],
        ['name' => 'Children', 'depth' => 2],
        ['name' => 'Children', 'depth' => 2],
        ['name' => 'Children', 'depth' => 2],
            ['name' => 'Children', 'depth' => 3],
    ['name' => 'Root_3', 'depth' => 1],
    ['name' => 'Root_4', 'depth' => 1],
        ['name' => 'Children', 'depth' => 2],
]));
```

demo: https://3v4l.org/1YkvY

Comment: Nice! :) I didn't have a good idea for how to implement what you did with `$path` there.

Comment: @Rarst Thanks! I'm still wondering if it can be done without references, but I have a feeling that then multiple loops would be necessary. 